# TWRP boot freeze (Pixel 5)

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, boot

I'm trying to install TWRP for the first time on my Pixel 5. I followed the instructions on https://twrp.me/google/googlepixel5.html, downloaded the latest image and bootet it with:

```
PS C:\platform-tools> ./fastboot boot .\twrp-3.6.2_11-0-redfin.img
Sending 'boot.img' (98304 KB)                      OKAY [  0.379s]
Booting                                            (bootloader) boot.img missing cmdline or OS version
OKAY [  2.274s]
Finished. Total time: 2.691s
```

On the phone, the TWRP starting screen shows up, but gets stuck there. I can execute the adb push command as stated in the instructions, but I cannot install it, as I can't get past this starting screen. Only thing that I can do here is a hard restart.

OS: Win10 / ProtonAOSP12

Comment: it requires ElementX-P5 kernel. It does not work on A12. please read 17 pages [support thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/4240711)

Comment: Thank you, @alecxs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question. As @alecxs pointed out, TWRP requires a Kernel with touch driver integrated. The only one I've found is ElementX-P5, which however does not work with Android 12.

Ultimately, I will not install TWRP. However, after research I've found many reports claiming TWRP unfortunately got pretty unstable on newer devices like the Pixel 5 either way.